# upgrading to magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 with php 8.1

Tags: composer, magento2.4.4, php8

I am upgrading Magento CE from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4-p1 with php 8.1
but I got this problem  facebook/graph-sdk does not support php 8.1 and it is PHP package not Magento 2 Module,

```
facebook/graph-sdk 5.6.2 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.6.1 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.6.0 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.5.0 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.4.4 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.4.3 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.4.2 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.4.1 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
- facebook/graph-sdk 5.4.0 requires php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.1.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

so my question is : how can I move this package to another directory like app/code and force using it after that I can fix bugs related to PHP 8.1

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add it to local I used this syntaxe in composer.json

under repositories

```
"repositories": {
   "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "facebook.local":{
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./packages/facebook/graph-sdk"

    },
```

}

after that I moved the content of php-graph-sdk to packages/facebook/graph-sdk and added support to php 8.1
finally I run composer update.
after that it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to following already?

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or maybe just

```
composer install --ignore-platform-req=php
```

When this is not the solution for you can indeed move it to `app/code`. Check the exact folder names in `registration.php`.

Example:

`Acme_Module` becomes `app/code/Acme/Module/<module files>`

Comment: thanks Akif, nut it wont work because facebook/graph-sdk is not a magento module it doesnt contain registration.php